# How to avoid errors from inexistent arguments in boost::program_options?

Tags: boost, command-line

I have trouble with `boost::program_options`. I have a piece of software composed of several subcomponents, each one of which can declare some options to be passed on the command line. I would like to stick to the following flow:

1. Configure boost::program_options with some options
2. Match options
3. Use matched options to initialize subcomponents
4. Subcomponents constructors declare more options
5. Match options again to configure components

So, at a certain instant of execution (2), I have only declared a number of options, but the program is actually called with the whole set of them (including the ones that will be declared in 3), causing a number of `unrecognised option '...'` errors. I can catch those, but the parsing will stop anyway. I have tried handling that with multiple `options_description` groups, I have also looked into command line styles (`style_t`) to see whether one of them allowed to ignore unmatched arguments. Do you have some more ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, sorry to bug you, but this could come handy to someone. Instead of using `parse_command_line`

```
auto parsed = parse_command_line(argc, argv, opts);
```

call `command_line_parser`'s `run` method explicitly after calling `allow_unregistered`

```
auto parsed = command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(opts).allow_unregistered().run();
```